# Sauna heater conduit from heater to sauna wall

Tags: wiring, heater, conduit

I am installing a Sauna-core 6Kw vaporizer model SV [manual PDF](https://www.saunaplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/SaunacoreStovemanual.pdf)

A UL listed LFMC with a temperature rating of 105C is requested for the wiring from the heater to the box.
Where can I find a few feet of this? 
Should the box to transition to the NM in the wall be mounted in the wall, or inside the sauna?

Thank you for your help!

Steve

Comment: If you've got a friend who is a professional electrician, he may have some laying around from a recent job, or she might find some at the shop. Otherwise, you go to the store and buy some. Most US big-box hardware/lumber stores sell a variety of wiring by the foot or in precut rolls/spools. If you can't find it at the big box, head to your local electrical supply house - almost guaranteed they'll have it. They may not have the 5-10' you need, but, they may have the end of a spool they're willing to part with, cheap.

Comment: Yeah, an electrical supply house is the first place I'd go.  Chicken-scratching around big-box stores for specialty stuff like this is the best way I know to get a) disappointed, or more likely b) handed the WRONG thing by an eager but ignorant stockboy.

Answer (score 1):

Every electric supply house I have been to sells LFMC by the foot, it's about $2/foot. Call it "metallic liquidtight", if you call it LFMC they often look at you funny and don't know what you are asking for.  I wouldn't even try a big box store and chance getting something imported that doesn't satisfy UL360 and NEC 501 as specified in your document.

I would stop the NM before entering the sauna, NM is not allowed in "damp" locations, and I'm sure the sauna would qualify as such. Being in a junction box that opens inside a damp location is normally interpreted as in the damp location, and I wouldn't attempt to argue that with an inspector.

Comment: I doubt the big-box stores would be selling non-listed liquidtight, either...the more likely issue would be you getting LFNC instead of LFMC (i.e. carflex instead of sealtite)

Answer (score 0):

Good ol' ebay.  Found someone selling Sealtite HTUA in various lengths with fittings. I bought an outdoor metal box with a moisture resistant cover (w/gasket) that I will mount entirely inside the sauna behind the heater.  Thanks for all the responses!